# How to get EXTRA (complimentary) results from bing-search API

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-search

When we generally search for a term in www.bing.com (e.g. newyork), we get some extra information along with search results on the right most side of the page.  Like for 'newyork' you would see some content from wikipedia, map location, it's twitter page etc.

Is there a way to get this information from current BING SEARCH API?

Answer (score 0):

Some of this information is available in the Bing Entity Search API here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-entity-search-api/.